# Is the NDK an a additional feature on top of the android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

Im a bit confused. Im developing an application which requires C++ audio libraries. To do this i must used the android NDK. Does the NDK support everything the SDK does with the added feature of using native libraries?

So in summary should i be developing the application using the NDK?

Any clarification is greatly appreciated

Comment: Based on the docs, you should avoid the ndk if possible, so I'm guessing no.

Comment: Based on the docs? Can you be more specific before you make such a sweeping statement?

Comment: I have seen the docs say that it is not advise to ot use the NDK to improve performance. What im really asking is does the NDK have all features and API's that the SDK does?

Answer (score 1):

In general you would use the NDK to give you functionality which you cannot currently get using the (Java) SDK or in otherwords you are adding additional lower-level functionality. Or that you need better performance from say graphics (an example being a game app).

You can use both the NDK and SDK to create a final app and to access your C code you would need to use the [Java Native Interface, JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Answer (score 1):

The NDK is an add-on to the SDK that allows you to build and debug native C/C++ shared libraries for your Android application.

You still need the SDK to package your application into a full Android package (.apk), or to install it to a device, or run it in the emulator.

If you don't use C/C++/Assembly code, you don't need the NDK period, just download the SDK.

If you use C/C++/Assembly, you need to download both the SDK and NDK.

The NDK provides a limited set of native APIs (e.g. for graphics and audio). Other platform APIs, which are Java-based, and provided by the framework, can be called from C/C++ through the JNI.